# How to generalise the interweaving of a list of NumPy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to interweave a list of `NumPy` arrays (that I call `parts_list` which can be of any `len`) in a particular way to form a large array. This large array always has an even number of dimensions, and will always have a shape of the form `(x, x)`, `(x, y, x, y)`, `(x, y, z, x, y, z)`, and so on. (Eventually, this would need to work for up to `12` dimensions, but `6` is fine for now).

When the large array has shape `(x, x)`, the parts will have shape `(x, 1)`; when the large array has shape `(x, y, x, y)`, the parts will have shape `(x, y, 1, y)`; then for `(x, y, z, x, y, z)`, it will be `(x, y, z, 1, y, z)`, and so on.

So, I can construct the array by doing for example:

```
original_size = [3, 4, 5]
large_array = np.zeros(tuple(list(original_size) +list(original_size)))
shp = large_array.shape # (3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5)
n_dimensions = len(shp)

for index in range(shp[0]): 
    array_part = parts_list[index]
    if n_dimensions == 6:
        large_array[:, :, :, index, :, :] = array_part[:, :, :, 0, :, :]
    elif n_dimensions == 4:
        large_array[:, :, index, :] = array_part[:, :, 0, :]
    elif n_dimensions == 2:
        large_array[:, index] = array_part[:, 0]
```

This piece of code works, but (for reasons that are long to explain) I need to modify it and make it work using functions like `hstack`, `block`, `reshape`, etc, instead of assigning slices like I'm currently doing.

So if, for `2` dimensions and a large array of shape `(3, 3)`, my `parts_list` is:

```
[array([[0],
        [1],
        [2]]),

 array([[3],
        [4],
        [5]]),

 array([[6],
        [7],
        [8]])]
```

The wanted result is:

```
array([[0., 3., 6.],
       [1., 4., 7.],
       [2., 5., 8.]])
```

I can get this result alternatively with:

```
np.block(parts_list)
```

If, for `4` dimensions and a large array of shape `(3, 2, 3, 2)`, my `parts_list` is:

```
[array([[[[ 0,  1]],
         [[ 2,  3]]],
        [[[ 4,  5]],
         [[ 6,  7]]],
        [[[ 8,  9]],
         [[10, 11]]]]),

 array([[[[12, 13]],
         [[14, 15]]],
        [[[16, 17]],
         [[18, 19]]],
        [[[20, 21]], 
         [[22, 23]]]]),

 array([[[[24, 25]], 
         [[26, 27]]],
        [[[28, 29]],
         [[30, 31]]], 
        [[[32, 33]],
         [[34, 35]]]])]
```

The wanted result is:

```
array([[[[ 0.,  1.],
         [12., 13.],
         [24., 25.]],

        [[ 2.,  3.],
         [14., 15.],
         [26., 27.]]],

       [[[ 4.,  5.],
         [16., 17.],
         [28., 29.]],

        [[ 6.,  7.],
         [18., 19.],
         [30., 31.]]],

       [[[ 8.,  9.],
         [20., 21.],
         [32., 33.]],

        [[10., 11.],
         [22., 23.],
         [34., 35.]]]])
```

I can make this work alternatively with:

```
np.dstack(parts_list)
```

However, I haven't been able to find an alternative way to get the same result for `6` dimensions and above. Is there are way of generalising this behaviour? I've tried many different combinations of funcions to no avail.

My biggest clue right now is that in the docs, about `dstack` it says:

```
This is equivalent to concatenation along the third axis after 2-D arrays of shape (M,N) have been reshaped to (M,N,1) and 1-D arrays of shape (N,) have been reshaped to (1,N,1). Rebuilds arrays divided by dsplit.
```

So maybe coding these instructions, and then extending the code could work, but it's not too clear to me. It may be much easier to find a solution based on the code that currently works (the one that uses slices).

Comment: Often this sort of thing can be done with a mix of `concatenate`, `stack`, `reshape` and `transpose`.  But there are so many different ways of "interweaving" arrays that it's hard to "generalize".

Comment: Hi. Yes, but I'm talking about generalising my particular case based on the code that works, so it can work for more dimensions without having to use slices. At least making this work for 6 dimensions without slicing would be an improvement.

Comment: I mean, you can see in the code that uses slices, that there's a clear pattern, so I'm just trying to find the way to follow the same pattern but without having to use slices.

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer using `block`. I'll publish it once the code is polished.

Answer (score 0):

This is the generalisation for all dimensions.

```
import numpy as np

def get_nested_parts(parts_list):
    # Get the number of different dimensions i.e. (x, y, z) instead of (x, y, z, x, y, z) 
    n_dimensions = len(parts_list[0].shape) // 2
    nested_parts_list = parts_list.copy()
    for i in range(n_dimensions-1):
        # Nest parts
        nested_parts_list = [[part] for part in nested_parts_list]
    return nested_parts_list

def generate_tensor_by_block(parts_list):
    nested_parts_list = get_nested_parts(parts_list)
    return np.block(nested_parts_list)
```